# Uniform distribution in polygon

Tags: distributions

For defined in the condition of random values:

The two -dimensional law of the distribution of the random vector $X_I = (X_{I_1}; X_{I_2})$, one-dimensional(1D) laws of the distribution of the components, the vector of the average and the covalization matrix;

The random values of the $X_{I_1}$ and $X_{I_2}$ are evenly distributed in the quadrangle with peaks $(2, 2), (1, -2), (-2, -2), (-2, 2)$.

In my decision, I divided the trapezoid into a rectangle and a triangle.

Please check my solution. I checked everything numerically using Wolfram Mathematica. Now I need to make sure my idea and its application are correct.

$S=4\cdot4-4\cdot1\cdot\frac12=14;$

$f_{\xi}(x;y)=\frac{1}{S}$ if $(x;y) \in D, 0$ otherwise$;$

$f\xi_{11}=\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{1}{S}\,dy=\frac{2}{7};$

$f\xi_{12}=\int_{4\cdot x-6}^{2}\frac{1}{S}\,dy=\frac{4-2\cdot x}{7};$

$f\xi_{2}=\int_{-2}^{\frac{y+6}{4}}\frac{1}{S}\,dx=\frac{y+14}{56};$

$E\xi_2=\int_{-2}^{2}y\cdot f\xi_{2}\,dy=\frac{2}{21};$

$E\xi_1=\int_{-2}^{1}x\cdot f\xi_{11}\,dx+\int_{1}^{2}x\cdot f\xi_{12}\,dx=-\frac{5}{21};$

$E\xi_2^2=\int_{-2}^{2}y^2\cdot f\xi_{2}\,dy=\frac{4}{3};$

$E\xi_1^2=\int_{-2}^{1}x^2\cdot f\xi_{11}\,dx+\int_{1}^{2}x^2\cdot f\xi_{12}\,dx=-\frac{47}{42};$

$D\xi_1=E\xi_1^2-(E\xi_1)^2=\frac{937}{882};$

$D\xi_2=E\xi_2^2-(E\xi_2)^2=\frac{584}{441};$

$\operatorname{cov}(\xi_1;\xi_2)=\int_{-2}^{2}(y-E\xi_2)\int_{-2}^{\frac{y+6}{4}}(x-E\xi_1)\,dx\,dy=\frac{146}{63};$

$\sum_{\xi}=((D\xi_1;\operatorname{cov}(\xi_1;\xi_2));(\operatorname{cov}(\xi_1;\xi_2);D\xi_2)).$

Image of the drawing:

[image]

Comment: RandomPoint is the simplest way of sampling from a region. For example `RandomPoint[Polygon[{{2, 2}, {1, -2}, {-2, -2}, {-2, 2}}], 1000]`.

Comment: Something to adjust in your calculation because the correlation coefficient between $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) for info) `146/63/Sqrt[(937/882)]/Sqrt[584/441] // N` equals `1.95384>1`

Comment: @StephenLuttrell: Your comment is misleading. The question is about the distribution , not about a sample from this distribution. If I were you, I'll delete such a comment as soon as possible.

Comment: This is a site about Wolfram Language and Mathematica. Please edit the question and include the relevant Mathematica code, otherwise the question is off-topic.

Comment: @user64494: As it stands, the question is not really about Wolfram Language and Mathematica, so I added a comment that is the closest WL/MMA thing that I could think of that is relevant — i.e. the (flat) distribution is defined as a polygonal WL region, and as a bonus WL gives you a simple way of sampling from such a region.

Comment: @StephenLuttrell: The right advice is `distr = ProbabilityDistribution[
   Piecewise[{{1/14, {x, y} \[Element] 
       Polygon[{{-2, -2}, {-2, 2}, {2, 2}, {1, -2}}]}, {0, 
      True}}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}];` Then, for example, `Mean[distr]` results in `{-(5/21), 2/21}`. I repeat if I were you, I'll delete such a misleading comment as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have cross-checked the algebra in your derivation, and I notice that you omitted the `1/S` normalisation factor from the integral over `x` and `y` in the penultimate line of your derivation.

On the other hand, if you were to use Wolfram Language to compute the covariance matrix of your region, then you could do it as follows:

Define the region.

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[{-2 <= x <= 3/2 + y/4, -2 <= y <= 2}, {x, y}];
```

Compute the centroid of the region.

```
cent = RegionCentroid[reg]

(* {-(5/21), 2/21} *)
```

Translate the region's centroid to the origin.

```
reg2 = Translate[reg, -cent];
```

Define the moment function.

```
mom[reg_, {i1_, i2_}] := 
  RegionMoment[reg, {i1, i2}] / RegionMoment[reg, {0, 0}];
```

Compute the covariance matrix.

```
cov = {{mom[reg2, {2, 0}], mom[reg2, {1, 1}]},
  {mom[reg2, {1, 1}], mom[reg2, {0, 2}]}}

(* {{937/882, 73/441}, {73/441, 584/441}} *)
```